Analogous mean value theorem for Jordan curves
Recently I came across the following theorem. Let $\Gamma$ be a Jordan curve and $F:\overline{int(\Gamma)} \to \mathbb{C}$ be continuous and analytic on $int(\Gamma))$. Then for each $z_0\in int(\Gamma)$ there exists two distinct points $z_1,z_2\in \Gamma$ such that
$$
F'(z_0) = \frac{F(z_2) - F(z_1)}{z_2-z_1}
$$
where by $int(\Gamma)$ is the unique bounded component of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \Gamma$. This theorem can be proved by employing the Osgood-Taylor-Caratheodory theorem, (and also an interesting/cool consequence is that every point inside the curve is the midpoint of some cord of the curve). In any case this is similar to the mean value theorem, and I was wondering if there is a similar theorem which would be precisely the mean value theorem. More precisely is it true that for any $z_1,z_2\in \Gamma$ there exists $z_0 \in int(\Gamma)$ so that,
$$
F'(z_0) = \frac{F(z_2) - F(z_1)}{z_2-z_1}
$$
or general is there some sort of mean value theorem (not property) for analytic functions. Thanks in advance.

Let $F(z)=e^z$ and $\Gamma$ be a circle of radius 4. Now, find distinct points $z_1, z_2\in \Gamma$ satisfying $F(z_1)=F(z_2)$.
